# Git commits keep local

Tags: git

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a commit for some changes that if I push, these commits do not get pushed with the other commits to the remote branch.

for example:
I've got some local changes i need for testing purposes. Like some changes to the config files and some json files. These changes will only be needed on this local branch and should never get on the remote branch. 
So when I create a commit I'm always trying to be carefull not to stage those exact files and every time I switch branches I need to stash and pop these changes.

So what I'm wondering is if there is a way within Git to keep those changes on the local branch without having to stash/pop or unstage them.

Comment: Have 2 branches, one you have local modifications only on (LOCAL), and the other where you do your real development (REAL). You would do any development you intend to share on the REAL branch and then merge this into LOCAL for testing. Push REAL, don't push LOCAL, and **never** merge LOCAL back into REAL. (REAL and LOCAL are just dummy names in my comment here, obviously you would come up with a better name for your local-only branch and the remote branch probably has a good name already).

Comment: Additionally, if those local changes are to configuration files there are better ways to handle this, such as committing only template configuration files and ignoring the real configuration files. In a fresh clone you would make a copy from the template to the real file and modify it for the local environment.

Comment: *"like some changes to the config files and some json files"* -- you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Values specific to each machine must never be stored in the repository. A template of the configuration file must be stored in the repo instead and the name of the actual configuration file must stay in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Even if you carefully maintain a local branch which never pushes to the remote branch, eventually the work you do may substantially diverge from the remote version of things.  At some point, you may be forced to bring your work into the remote branch, to avoid things like nasty merge conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this but it depends on the extent of your local modifications.

Let's first assume you have some configuration files in your repository. These configuration files may contain things such as the local hostname, connection strings or similar for databases, etc.

In this situation the best way is to only commit template configuration files.

For instance, if the application needs a file named `app.config` to be present, but this file contains such things, you would instead commit a template file named `app.config.template`. This file would not contain actual hostnames, usernames, etc. but at most contain placeholders where you're expected to add this information.

Then, in your build script (or similar) you would have something that would look like this:

```
IF NOT EXIST app.config COPY app.config.template app.config
```

This would, if needed, make a fresh copy from the template to the real file, on build.

Additionally, you would instruct git to ignore the real file:

```
# in .gitignore
app.config
```

Now, sometimes this is not enough. It should be, but sometimes it isn't.

In this situation a different approach would use an extra branch for this. Let's assume you're developing on a branch named `develop`.

You would then first create a new branch for your local *only* modifications:

```
git branch develop-local develop
```

Then you would check out this branch, make all the necessary *local* modifications, and commit these:

```
git checkout develop-local
# hack hack hack
git add .
git commit -m "LOCAL modifications for test environment"
```

Then you would switch back to the real branch and work on a case:

```
git checkout develop
# work work work
git add .
git commit -m "Case #123, fixed bug in SQL parsing"
```

To test this, go back to your local branch, merge in the real branch and test:

```
git checkout develop-local
git merge develop
# test test test
```

Finally:

- **never** push `develop-local`, only `develop`
- **never** merge `develop-local` back into `develop`

Comment: Note that some of these commands can be combined but for the sake of the explanation I opted not to. Additionally, if you happen to push the local branch to the remote, no harm other than an extra branch should be done as the changes aren't integrated into `develop`. So unless you store proprietary information that cannot leave your local system **at all**, at most you would have to delete that branch from the remote if you happen to push it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it’s a little cumbersome.

Read [7.6 Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) from the docs.

Comment: I think they won't be able to push if he modified history without forcing the remote branch to follow their local modification

Answer (score 0):

I usually configure my projects to include files like *main.config* and then *local.config* if only it is exist and then merge them in a propper way. And those local files are **.gitignore**'d of course.

Depends on your architecture, the article on [.git/info/exclude](https://hackernoon.com/exclude-files-from-git-without-committing-changes-to-gitignore-986fa712e78d) can be handy

Answer (score -1):

Consider using assume unchanged:

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.

[git-update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) from the docs.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged app.config
```

That would stop `app.config` from being marked as changed.

‘[temporarily ignoring files](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html)’ is probably also worth a read.